# Как скопировать SSH ключи с Windows в Ubuntu для git

Tags: git, ssh

Скопировал файлы id_rsa and id_rsa.pub с Windows и бросил в папку ~/.ssh в Ubuntu. доступа еще нет. Генерировать новые ключи не вариант из-за ограничений

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы заработало - нужно еще правильно раздать права на private key,

что то вроде

```
    chmod 400 id_rsa
```

После этого должно заработать. Если нет - приведите текст сообщения об ошибке, будем еще думать

Comment: для людей мнемоника всё-таки как-то проще звучит, чем восьмиричная арифметика: `u=r,go=` (это вместо `400`).